# How do we change url in Business Central 365 embedded Power BI reports when the user changes companies

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-business-central, microsoft-dynamics-nav

We have created some custom Power BI reports that are embedded in Business Central Item List, Customer List and Vendor List pages. They work fine and display as expected, UNTIL the user changes the Company via MySettings. The Power BI reports embedded in the List pages noted above still all point back to the original company, NOT the newly selected company.

The Power BI reports are populated via Business Central 365 Web Services queries which include the Company Name in the ODataV4 url that is exposed.

How can we pass the new Company name back to Power BI so the url can be updated. Does this possibly have something to do with the alternate Url for the Company Name where it is exposed as a parameter via ?Company?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

The Power BI report is linked to a web service which is linked to a specific company in Business Central (which under the hoods means a company specific SQL table).

A possible solution could be to create the same Power BI report pr. company and then create an extension for Business Central that switches to the correct Power BI report when the company is changed.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions or pseudo code about switching to the correct Power BI report?

Comment: Personally I would start by investigating the base application and the objects used for the embedded Power BI reports. I haven't worked much with the Power BI areas in Business Central yet, so that is my default course of action.